# How do I combine my two programs into one?

Tags: java, encryption, methods

I have created a encryption program and a decryption program but there completely separate files. I also used different variable names and such is there a way to combine them without having to change all the names of variables and such?

encryption code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cipher //This class will encrpyt the program
{

  public static char cipher (int j){ //this mehtod generates the random letter
    char[] cipher1 = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'}; //characters for char array
    j = (int) (Math.random() * cipher1.length);//choose a random element from the array
    return cipher1[j]; //this will return the letter
  } //end of cipher method

  public static void main (String[] args){ //main method

    System.out.print("Please type a sentence to be encrypted\n");//asks user for their word to be encrypted
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //imports scanner reader
    String userinput = inputScanner.next(); //assigns the word entered by user to varible userinput

    userinput = userinput.toUpperCase(); //userinput in transferred to upper case letters
    int yu = userinput.length(); //yu finds the length of charceters in userinput
    char[] charArray = userinput.toCharArray(); //sends userinput to charArray

    int w=1; //used for try catch block
    System.out.println("please enter pattern"); //prompt for pattern
    String pattern = inputScanner.next(); //pattern will decide how many characters will be input in the encrypted code
    int pattern2 = Integer.parseInt(pattern); //changes the string value to integer value

    do{ 
      try{ //try block to catch if user enters letters or decimal numbers
        w=2;

        if(pattern2<0){
          System.out.println("please enter a number above 0"); //prompt if user enters somthing below zero
          w=1;
        }
      }catch (NumberFormatException f){
        System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER!"); //prompt if user enters something user than a number
      }

    }while (w==1); //end of do and try catch block

    System.out.print("your encrypted code is: "); //prompt to give user encrypted code

    for(int i = 0; i < yu; i++){
      System.out.print(charArray[i]);

      for(int q = 0; q < pattern2; q++){
        System.out.print( cipher(1));
      } //end of for loop
    } //end of for loop

  } //end of main method
} //cipher class
```

decryption code:

```
   import java.util.*;

public class unscrambler //This class will encrpyt the program
{
 public static void main (String [] args){
   int cip= 0;
   String user ="";




   System.out.println("Please enter the code to unscramble"); 
   Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //imports scanner reader
    String userinput = inputScanner.next();
    char[] charArray = userinput.toCharArray(); //sends userinput to charArray
    int j=charArray.length;

    Character [] array = new Character[j];

    for(int w=0; w<j; w++){
      array[w] = charArray[w];
    }

    int a=1;
               System.out.println("Please enter the number cipher pattern (an integer)");
    do{
      try{

         user = inputScanner.next();
        cip = Integer.parseInt(user);
        a=2;
        System.out.println("your code is ");

 for(int w =0; w<j;){
   System.out.println(charArray[j]);

   w+=cip;
 }
          if(cip<=0){
          System.out.println("please enter number greater than zero");
a=1;
}
}catch(NumberFormatException f){
  System.out.println("please enter a proper number");
}
}while(a==1);


 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can just use the following steps.

1. Rename `main` in the second class, and move the code content as a separate method into the first class.
2. Rename `main` in the first class.
3. Make a new main that will use a command line argument to disambiguate between them.

To be more specific, your code will now look like this:

```
public class Cipher {
 public static char cipher (int j){
... 
}
// Old main1
public static void encrypt() {
...
}
// Old main2
public static void decrypt() {
...
}
// One possible way to disambiguate, there are many others.
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (args[0].equals("encrypt") encrypt();
   else decrypt();
}
}
```

Note that I removed `String[] args` from your two old mains, because you did not seem to be using them.

Answer (score 0):

Keep them as separate files. 
1) Rename main in first class to encrypt
2) Rename main in second class to decrypt
3) Create a new class with a main method. 
   a) Create objects in the main method for encrypt and decrypt
   b) call them whenever you require like Cipher.encypt() and descrambler.decrypt()

It will be good design that the two classes for encrypt and decrypt remain separate and you can reuse it later without any modifications.